# Using Substring in javascript to collect values in a array

Tags: javascript, html

I have data in a single field which is as below:

```
40-818-938 | COUPLING, 25MM, PVC BLACK | PCS, MTR, BUNDLE | 3
```

The first block is the item code, second is the item description, third are the units, they are dynamic, and fourth is the number of units. The blocks are separated by `|`

I want to loop through the third block (units) and put them into separate variables without commas and spaces and use them to populate a select list.

Kindly help me in achieving that. Below is the code which adds the third block into a select list according to the number of units (fourth block), I need to separate them.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrData[3]; i++) {
 var x = document.createElement("OPTION");
    x.setAttribute("value", arrData[2]);
    var t = document.createTextNode(arrData[2]);
    x.appendChild(t);
input.appendChild(x);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "40-818-938 | COUPLING, 25MM, PVC BLACK | PCS, MTR, BUNDLE | 3".split("|")[2].split(",")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've already split the original string into an array, you just need to also split the 2nd element of that array:

```
arrData[2] = arrData[2].split(',');
```

Then, inside the loop, you need to reference it like so:

```
x.setAttribute("value", arrData[2][i]);
var t = document.createTextNode(arrData[2][i]);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6s6a9dc/)

Answer (score 2):

```
Var items = obj.split("|"); 
Var units = items[2].split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the spaces as well, you can add them to the pattern to split on:

```
var data = '40-818-938 | COUPLING, 25MM, PVC BLACK | PCS, MTR, BUNDLE | 3';

var units = data.split(/\s*\|\s*/g)[2]; // "PCS, MTR, BUNDLE"

console.log(units.split(/\s*,\s*/)[1]); // "MTR"
```

and the simplest way to make an *option* element is to use the [*Option* constructor](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-option-element.html#dom-option):

```
var unit = units.split(/\s*,\s*/)[1];
var x = new Option(unit, unit);
input.appendChild(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
var string1 = yourstring.split('|');
var array = string1[2] .split(',');
```

Build a select:

```
array.forEach(function(entry) {
  var x = document.createElement("OPTION");
  x.setAttribute("value", entry);
  var t = document.createTextNode(entry);
  x.appendChild(t);
  input.appendChild(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use split function of java script. Ex.

```
var newstring=string.split('|');
var laststring=newstring[2].split(",");// new string
var yourneed=laststring[1];
```